# How to apply a $(document).ready function to asynchronously loaded elements?

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following function which applies watermark text to any text box on the page with the id `"Search"`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#Search").watermark({
        watermarkClass: 'watermarkOn',
        defaultText: $("#Search").attr("watermarkText")
    });
});
```

The problem I'm having is that that this doesn't get applied when I asynchronously load a panel that contains the text box, because it occurs in the `jQuery(document).ready` function, which has already fired.

Is there anything I can do to make sure that any asynchronously loaded text boxes have this function applied to them? Thanks.

Comment: How are the elements being loaded?  Also, do you have more than one element with `id="Search"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `$(selector).load()`, then call the `.watermark()` in the callback.

```
$('someSelector').load('/some/path', function( response ) {
    $('someNewElement').find('input').watermark({
        watermarkClass: 'watermarkOn',
        defaultText: $("#Search").attr("watermarkText")
    });
});
```

If the options are all the same, you could store them in a variable to be reused.

```
var options = {
           watermarkClass: 'watermarkOn',
           defaultText: $("#Search").attr("watermarkText")
          };

$("#Search").watermark( options );

$('someSelector').load('/some/path', function( response ) {
    $('someNewElement').find('input').watermark( options );
});
```

Comment: Find some way of calling it after you asynchronously load the content. Even if its not load(), however you're doing it will have a way of executing code on the successful completion of the script.

Answer (score 0):

look up the `.live()` method to bind events, to elements created previously, or in the future, as in your case, asynchronously.

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/live/

It may be possible to alter the `watermark` plugin / method you have to use `.live()`

`.live()` will only work for events and it won't allow you to attach a plugin to elements that will be created in the future.

For that you can look at [liveQuery](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/livequery/) a plugin that will allow you to attach plugins to elements that may be created in the future.

eg.

```
//initiate the watermark plugin on all elements with class 'search' existing now or created in the future.
    $('.Search').livequery(function() {
        $(this).watermark({
            watermarkClass: 'watermarkOn',
            defaultText: $("#Search").attr("watermarkText")
        });
    });
```

Comment: even with your edit, this isn't how things work...I don't mean this to sound rude though it will, *no* answer is better than a wrong one, and you've posted many of these the past few days.

Comment: @Nick - no offence taken mate. I've learnt more as a result of posting 'wrong' answers. Could you point out what you make out to be 'many' of them?

Comment: Also I know `.live()` doesn't work with plugins, its event based. Events which a plugin may use, therefore being able to leverage off `.live()`

Comment: You simply can't use `.live()` for this...when a new element is added things need to be done to it, namely adding the watermark class and probably some sort of `focus`/`blur` behavior...`.live()` can't do this, it has no knowledge of added elements, so it has no mechanism to recognize elements added to the DOM and add classes/properties to them.  This is true of *most* plugins, otherwise it wouldn't be a plugin, it'd be a simple `.live()` handler.